# With the article or without

Tags: articles

I'm writing an essay about Transport. I wrote "Nowadays there is goob public transport in a lot of countries and cities. There is bus, aircraft, train, taxi..."
Is it correct that I wrote "...bus, aircraft, train, taxi..." without the article? I mean it in the general. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> There is bus, aircraft, train, taxi...

It sounds a little weird. Using plurals you can kill two birds with one stone:

```
There are buses, aircraft, trains, taxis...
```

Answer (score 0):

[Note: In AmE, it would be "public transportation".]

If a noun is used as a noun adjunct, then it generally doesn't take an article for itself (although the noun that it modifies might). So it would be correct to says "There is bus, aircraft, train, and taxi transportation." Even without the word "transportation" at the end, it would probably be understood. You also could say "There is transportation by bus, aircraft, train, and taxi." But if you're talking about a particular bus, train, and taxi, they need an article.